# How to say remove all the content with in style='' from regular expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to format html document and it has full of inline css. I use notpad++ and try regular expression to format it.
I want to replace style='font-family:"Arial","sans-serif"....... etc ' with style=''

How to do this with regular expressions?

I am new to regular expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace :

```
style='[^']+'
```

with:

```
style=''
```

- `[^']+` matches one or more characters that is not quote(`'`)

Comment: Superb, would this have also worked for double quotes (not that I coud not have run a find and replace double to single) but just curious?